# Can not inject $modal from AngularUI in Angular controller

Tags: angularjs, modal-dialog, angular-ui

I have issues injecting $modal in my Angular app. I am failing even the simplest demos.

Here are parts of my code:

**index.html**

```
<script src="lib/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.10.0.js"></script>
<script src="js/services.js"></script>
<script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
<script src="js/filters.js"></script>
<script src="js/directives.js"></script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
```

**app.js**

```
var App= angular.module('App', [
  'ngRoute',
  'ui.bootstrap', ...];
```

**controllers.js**

```
kanbanControllers.controller('ModalDemoCtrl',["$scope", "$modal", function ($scope, $modal) {

  $scope.items = ['item1', 'item2', 'item3'];

}]);
```

The error it gives me is:

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $modalProvider <- $modal
```

What should I do?

Comment: poste please angular version and all res you loaded

Comment: angular version - 1.2.10